# How to modify _source parameters in Elasticsearch mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, elastic-stack

I'm new to Elasticsearch (ELK) and I'm working on a project initially done by an external company, but they won't support it so I'm trying to making some changes myself.

What I'm trying to do is changing a field name, since the data coming into Elasticsearch now has changed a bit.

If I run this:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty'
```

I get the mappings (I guess is the word). It looks like this (simplified a bit):

```
{
    "_index" : ".kibana",
    "_type" : "visualization",
    "_id" : "Count-By-Clusters",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source":{
        "title":"Count by Clusters",
        "visState":"{
            "type": "histogram",
            "params": {},
            "aggs": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "type": "terms",
                    "schema": "group",
                    "params": {  
                        "field": "cluster.id",  
                        "size": 5,  
                        "order": "desc",  
                        "orderBy": "1"
                    }  
                },
                {
                    ...
                }   
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "_index" : ".kibana",
    "_type" : "visualization",
    "_id" : "Users-By-Clusters",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source":{
        "title":"Users by Clusters",
        "visState":"{
            "type": "histogram",
            "params": {},
            "aggs": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "type": "terms",
                    "schema": "group",
                    "params": {  
                        "field": "cluster.id",  
                        "size": 5,  
                        "order": "desc",  
                        "orderBy": "1"
                    }  
                },
                {
                    ...
                }  
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

There are eight of these mappings, I just showed two of them.

The problem is, that `"field": "cluster.id"` now has to be `"field": "cluster_id"` and I can't seem to find a way to change that.

I even tried to just create new mappings, but I get the error message saying `.kibana` already exists, even though I already have not just one, but eight of these mappings with `"_index" : ".kibana"`.

I've searched the documentation but I'm still stuck. Maybe I'm looking the wrong places. I would appreciate help and/or pointers to how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error which you are getting is because .kibana is the default index.
You can re-try by first deleting .kibana index using following command:-

> curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/.kibana

where localhost is your Elasticsearch server address followed by port.

After deleting it try to create mappings as you have been trying.